# Issue Decoding Child Models as Properties with JSONDecoder?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, swift5, jsondecoder

Any clue why my decoding is not working properly? I've created 3 models: `Portfolio`, `Tokens`, and `Holdings`, and for some reason `Holdings` is causing issues, not sure if it's the structure, but here's the json:

```json
{
  "address": "0x9fa108d355d62e7ceb3a616d0a4249be3795c182",
  "updated_at": "2022-01-03T01:29:02.860917922Z",
  "next_update_at": "2022-01-03T01:34:02.860919113Z",
  "quote_currency": "USD",
  "chain_id": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "contract_decimals": 8,
      "contract_name": "Wrapped BTC",
      "contract_ticker_symbol": "WBTC",
      "contract_address": "0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599",
      "supports_erc": null,
      "logo_url": "https://logos.covalenthq.com/tokens/1/0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599.png",
      "holdings": [
        {
          "timestamp": "2022-01-03T00:00:00Z",
          "quote_rate": 47119.83,
          "open": {},
          "high": {},
          "low": {},
          "close": {}
     },
{},
{},
...
```

And here's my models:

```swift
struct HistoricPortfolioResponse: Codable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let address: String
    let updatedAt: Date
    let nextUpdateAt: Date
    let quoteCurrency: String
    let chainId: Int
    let tokenResponses: [TokenResponse]

    // MARK: - Coding Keys

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case address
        case updatedAt
        case nextUpdateAt
        case quoteCurrency
        case chainId
        case tokenResponses = "items"
    }

    // MARK: - Initializing the Struct

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.address = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
        self.chainId = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .chainId)
        self.nextUpdateAt = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .nextUpdateAt)
        self.quoteCurrency = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .quoteCurrency)
        self.updatedAt = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .updatedAt)
        self.tokenResponses = try values.decode([TokenResponse].self, forKey: .tokenResponses)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TokenResponse: Codable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let contractAddress: String
    let decimals: Int
    let iconURL: String
    let name: String
    let tickerSymbol: String
    let holdings: [HoldingsResponse]

    // MARK: - Coding Keys

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case contractAddress
        case decimals = "contractDecimals"
        case iconURL = "logoUrl"
        case name = "contractName"
        case tickerSymbol = "contractTickerSymbol"
        case holdings = "holdings"
    }

    // MARK: - Initializing the Model

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.contractAddress = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .contractAddress)
        self.decimals = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .decimals)
        self.iconURL = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .iconURL)
        self.name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.tickerSymbol = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .tickerSymbol)
        self.holdings = try values.decode([HoldingsResponse].self, forKey: .holdings)
    }
}
```

and `holdings` which is causing the issue:

```swift
struct HoldingsResponse: Codable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let timestamp: String
    let quotePrice: Double

    // MARK: - Coding Keys

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timestamp
        case quotePrice = "quoteRate"
    }

    // MARK: - Initializing the Response Model

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.timestamp = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .timestamp)
        self.quotePrice = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .quotePrice)
    }
}
```

Sadly, I keep seeing this error: `Error: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.` . This is how I'm parsing the data atm:

```swift
if let data = data {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    jsonDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

    do {
        let historicPortfolioData = try jsonDecoder.decode(HistoricPortfolioResponse.self, from: data)
         completion(.success(historicPortfolioData))
    } catch {
         completion(.failure(error))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share complete JSON Data?

Comment: How do you print the error? I don’t think you understand what the CodingKeys enum is for and how to use it. Read [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) from Apple on encoding and decoding

Answer (score 0):

I guess your model is incorrect try this models

```
struct TokenResponse: Codable {

// MARK: - Properties

let contractAddress: String
let decimals: Int
let iconURL: String
let name: String
let tickerSymbol: String
let holdings: [HoldingsResponse]

// MARK: - Coding Keys

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case contractAddress = "contract_address"
    case decimals = "contract_decimals"
    case iconURL = "logo_url"
    case name = "contract_name"
    case tickerSymbol = "contract_ticker_symbol"
    case holdings = "holdings"
}

// MARK: - Initializing the Model

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.contractAddress = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .contractAddress)
    self.decimals = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .decimals)
    self.iconURL = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .iconURL)
    self.name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.tickerSymbol = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .tickerSymbol)
    self.holdings = try values.decode([HoldingsResponse].self, forKey: .holdings)
}
}

struct HoldingsResponse: Codable {

// MARK: - Properties

let timestamp: String
let quotePrice: Double

// MARK: - Coding Keys

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case timestamp
    case quotePrice = "quote_rate"
}

// MARK: - Initializing the Response Model

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.timestamp = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .timestamp)
    self.quotePrice = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .quotePrice)
}
}
```